# Is it possible to get the form state in a separate component using react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, next.js13

I have two search forms - one is a search input field in header and another is in sidebar with different filters.

In sidebar form, i have a header and in the header I want to show a reset button if any filter has value (isDirty from react-hook-form).

I can use isDirty field from react-hook-form to show this in sidebar as it is the same component.

However, search input in header is totally different component and not connected with sidebar component in direct way. I also want to show reset button in sidebar header if this search input has value.

But the issue is how can I know if there is value in search input i.e. header form is dirty.

How can I show reset button in sidebar header, irrespective of which form is dirty and reset the values in both form on click of it?

Please provide suggestions and ideas.

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hoist the `useForm` to a common ancestor and have two separate values for each input defined in that `useForm`. Now pass down the relevant functions/values to both components. They can now see each others values and also access the metadata about if the state is dirty or not.

Comment: both input field/component has no parent/child relationship that's why created two different forms. props can't be passed down from common ancestors

Comment: There's *always* a common ancestor unless you are in the tiny minority with multiple react roots (legacy integrations). It does not need to be the direct parent. For example, the highest level is `<App>` or your equivalent. That is a common ancestor. Not saying it should be that high necessarily but there will be a common ancestor. You would usually pick the "deepest" common one. This is a classic hoisting state problem.

Comment: Props passing will be a issue in this case. As event sidebar and search input these are reusable component and will be rendered based on page

Comment: Thats fine. In this case, you simply need to put/use the common ancestor below the route level for relevant routes only. You could also avoid tiresome prop drilling by just sticking the form state in a context provider in that common ancestor.

Comment: I implemented by keeping form state in zustand and then setting and storing zustand whenever form state changes, now I can pick isDirty from zustand store in any component